# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp())

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to create a SignIn page with Firebase authentication, but this error is happening in main.dart when I run the code:

[image: error]

This is the code: from main.dart:

```
import 'package:app_mypocket/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:app_mypocket/telas/home/homepage.dart';
import 'package:app_mypocket/telas/login/telalogin.dart';
[import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  //  widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Pocket',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
    ),
      home: HomePage(),
      //routes: routes,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            return HomePage();
          } else{
            return TelaLogin();
          }
        })
    );
}
```

My pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl:
  provider: ^6.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
  fl_chart: ^0.55.2
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
```

Also, I have created a user manually in my project on the firebase website, so I am trying to logIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When logging into Firebase you normally provide options, like:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
```

These firebase_options are generated by running "flutterfire configure"  (previously firebase configure iirc).

I think you forget this specific step. See the guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios

The configuration file contains information about the apiKey, appId, projectId, bundle/app name and much more. Not providing it, will lead to a default/blank/unusable app.